# move object to another position (blinking)

Tags: unity-game-engine

What i mean by blinking, is that the object is instantly move(change) to another (specific)position but not slowly or without showing the path of movement? its like popping out to another position

[image]

the box are the positions, when press right the object goes to next position to the right and when press left the object goes to next position to the left.

```
public float speed;
```

`if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow))`
         `transform.Translate (new Vector3 (-speed, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime);`

`if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))`
         `transform.Translate (new Vector3 (speed, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime);`

How do i do this with my code?

Comment: You've already shown code that seems to do what you want. Can you clarify what you mean in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to move instantly an *x* amount to the left and to the right according to the user input, you can use GetKeyDown insted of GetKey to just make "one move" each time the key is pressed.

But if you want to leave the key pressed and see it move *x* amount every *t* time you can use a timer and just move when *t* time has passed since the last move. Making it "blink" like you say. Something like this:

```cs
public float speed = 10;//the x amount moved
public float timeToMove = 0.5f; //the t time to "blink"

private float timer;

void Start () {
    timer = timeToMove; //initially you can move
}

void Update () {
    //add time to the timer
    if(timer < timeToMove){
        timer += Time.deltaTime; 
    }


    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
        //only move if the time has passed
        if (timer >= timeToMove){
            transform.Translate (new Vector3 (-speed, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime);

            timer = 0; //reset the timer
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the object moves to the left every 0.5 seconds making it blink. You can do the same for the right and you can set the speed and time to make it move as you like.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this where pos3 is the starting position, too3 is the end position, and step3 is the speed it is moving from pos3 to too3

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(pos3, too3, step3);
```